# ajax success but laravel is not inserting into database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm having extremely hard time with my upvote/downvote system. ajax executes the success function however laravel doesn't insert anything into the database.. i have no clue what am i doing wrong. my AJAX:

```
$('[data-value]').on('click', function () {
  $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
  });
  var $this = $(this);
  var post_id = $this.data('id');
  var votetype = $this.data('value');
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:'/post/' + post_id + '/vote/' + votetype,
    success:vote(post_id,votetype)
  });
  // vote(post_id,votetype);
  });
```

My route:

```
Route::post('/post/{id}/vote/{vote}', 'PostController@vote');
```

My laravel Vote function:

```
  public function vote($id,$vote)
    {
      //TODO: refactor this..
      $username = Session::get('username');
      $id = Post::find($id);
      $uservote = PostVotes::where('id',$id)->where('username',$username)->first();
      if($uservote->count())
      {
        $votetype = $uservote->vote;
        if($votetype === $vote)
        {
            $uservote->delete();
        } else {
          Vote::updateOrCreate(
             ['vote' => $votetype],
             ['vote' => $vote]
           );
        }
      } else {
        $uservote = new PostVotes;
        $uservote->vote = $vote;
        $uservote->username = $username;
        $uservote->id = $id;
        $uservote->save();
      }
    }
```

I don't know if this is necessary but here is my migration

```
class CreatePostVotesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('post_votes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id');
            $table->string('username',50);
            $table->integer('vote');

        });
    }
}

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id')->unique;
            $table->string('title',80);
            $table->string('username',50);
            $table->integer('score');
            $table->timestamp('created_at');
            $table->string('image',512);
        });
    }
 }
```

Relationships: (Post.php):

```
public function votes()
    {
      //Quick note: Id refers to the post id.
      return $this->hasMany(PostVotes::class,'id');
    }
```

PostVotes.php:

```
public function post()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(Post::class,'id');
    }
```

Comment: where are you declaring this `vote(post_id,votetype)` function?

Comment: how you relates both tables ? You should have one column `post_id` in `post_votes` table

Comment: @hassan in the main.js file.. i don't think the problem is with ajax maybe i'm doing something wrong in the vote function (in the Controller)

Comment: @Niklesh edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure that one of the problems is here:

```
$id = Post::find($id);
/*
 * you are passing instance of the Post model or null into where('id', $id) 
 * predicate, instead of the id of the post
 */
$uservote = PostVotes::where('id',$id)->where('username',$username)->first();
```

You can try to change this:

```
$post = Post::find($id);
$uservote = PostVotes::where([
        'id' => $post->id,
        'username' => $username,
    ])
    ->first();
```

Because you are passing instance of the model `Post` (or `null`, if `Post::find($id)` returns nothing) into your condition instead of the post `id` attribute.

**Addition:**

Before using `$uservote` you should check `$uservote`:

```
$uservote = PostVotes::where([
        'id' => $post->id,
        'username' => $username,
    ])
    ->first();

// $uservote is empty, you should create new instance of the PostVotes model
if( empty($uservote)){
}
```

Also you can pass `$id` which is parameter of your function `vote`, if this `id` is the id of the post.

```
$uservote = PostVotes::where([
        'id' => $id, // <-- use $id, if $id is the post id
        'username' => $username,
    ])
    ->first();
```

If you want to store id of the post into your Vote model, probably you should change this:

```
$uservote->id = $id;
```

On this:

```
$uservote->id = $post->id;
```

After accepting my suggestions about your code, when `$post = Post::find($id);`

By the way, for the better readability, you should rename `id` attribute of your model `Vote` into `post_id`, if you want store id of the post in this attribute. Usually, field with the name `id` uses as table primary key with auto increment attribute.

Also look at the `/storage/logs/laravel.log` file, where you can find more information about errors.

**Addition #2**

You should get something like this:

```
public function vote($id, $vote)
{
    //TODO: refactor this..
    $username = Session::get('username');
    $post = Post::find($id);

    if( empty($post) ){
        abort(404, 'Cannot find post');
    }

    $uservote = PostVotes::where([
            'id' => $post->id,
            'username' => $username,
        ])
        ->first();

    // replace $uservote->count() with !empty($userwote), because you cannot call count() nethod from null
    if (!empty($uservote)) {
        $votetype = $uservote->vote;
        if ($votetype === $vote) {
            $uservote->delete();
        } else {
            Vote::updateOrCreate(
                ['vote' => $votetype], ['vote' => $vote]
            );
        }
    } else {
        $uservote = new PostVotes();
        $uservote->vote = $vote;
        $uservote->username = $username;
        $uservote->id = $post->id; // <!-- probably replace `id` field name on `post_id`
        $uservote->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: idk if this will help but there is a production error that throws a fatalthrowablerror in laravel.log that says call to member function count() on null

Comment: I updated my answer about this next problem. You should check `$uservote` before using and create new one, if $uservote is empty: `if(empty($uservote)){ // create new PostVotes instance ...`

Comment: i'm sorry i'm kinda confused where do i put if(empty($uservote))? can you change my code?

Comment: I added possible version of the function `vote` at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: i'm starting to think this is a problem with my routing.. because if i do http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/1/vote/1 in the url it says methodnotallowedhttpexception..

Comment: actually never mind thanks for your help i got it working by putting public $timestamps = false; it was giving me updated_at column error.. freaking laravel and it's terrible error handlig

Comment: I cannot write the whole thing for you. You cannot just open this link `127.0.0.1:8000/post/1/vote/1`, because your route allows only `post` method, not `get` method. If you want to open this link and check function, you should temporary replace `Route::post('/post/{id}/vote/{vote}', 'PostController@vote');` with `Route::get('/post/{id}/vote/{vote}', 'PostController@vote');`. Laravel has pretty good error handling, all the card in your hands. If my answer was useful, please check it as solution and vote.

Answer (score 0):

Return OK from the server only after data has successfully inserted into the database.

The server could return OK but data has not actually been inserted into the database. The jquery success function would be executed without having achieved what the system is expected to do